# Make background image responsive in xamarin forms uwp app

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, content-pages

How to adjust the background image of content page when the screen is resized in xamarin forms uwp app.

I have added the background image for Content page as below.But when I am resizing the size of the screen the image is shrinking.How can i avoid this behavior?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:absmobilityapp="clr-namespace:example"
         xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:example.CustomControls"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         x:Class="example.Views.LoginPage"
         BackgroundImage="Images/bg.png"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
</ContentPage>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I do not think you have this privilege yet, you might want to use an `AbsoluteLayout`  and set the background image yourself and see if that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the BackgroundImage from the page and instead of that you create a Layout of your choice and put the BackgroundImage in there.